# Problems in usage of JSP's <c:forEach>

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am trying to iterate through Collection of items:

```
<c:forEach items="#{tree.items}" var="item">
    <h:commandLink rendered="#{item.type == 'category'}" action="#{item.onNodeClicked}"
```

Hovewer, i've got an exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'type'.

Looks like JSP recognizes tree items as String objects. What i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. The `#{item}` is only available during view build time, while the `rendered` attribute is evaluated during view render time.

Use `<c:if>` instead.

```html
<c:forEach items="#{tree.items}" var="item">
    <c:if test="#{item.type == 'category'}">
        <h:commandLink ... action="#{item.onNodeClicked}" />
```

Or, if you're on JSF2 (which is out for more than 3 years), replace that legacy JSP by its successor [Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info) and use its `<ui:repeat>` component instead. It's evaluated during view render time as well.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{tree.items}" var="item">
    <h:commandLink rendered="#{item.type == 'category'}" action="#{item.onNodeClicked}" />
```

Comment: I should note that problem appears after changes in dependencies. The code has not been changed.